# How to create a .tar.gz file owned by a specific owner and group?

Tags: tar, chown, ownership

I want to create a `tar.gz` file of a directory which will be owned by a certain user and group (and not by `root`, who is creating the archive).

Basically, I want to combine the following to one single step:

```
tar -cvz -f temp-backup.tar.gz temp/
chown absonegative:absonegative temp-backup.tar.gz
```

Is that possible in one single pass? I want to avoid that there is a (albeit very small) period in which the file exists as `root:root`, as my current backup solution has problems with that (I am trying to fix that as well).

Note that I want to retain the ownership of the files inside the archive, as is already covered if you execute `tar` as `root`. I only want to alter the ownership of the result.

Comment: @Rinzwind they don't have a duplication problem, they just want to combine the two commands into one :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine into one step you can do something along the lines of

```
tar -cvzf - temp/ | su absonegative -c "dd of=temp-backup.tar.gz"
```

This assumes that the default group of the `absonegative` account is also `absonegative`

Comment: I did not know about `dd`. That's what I need here. I will try it out and let you know. Thank you Doug!

Comment: What does `su: must be run from a terminal` mean in this context? I get that when doing the above.

Comment: There are quite a few hits on this error message if you'll put a little research into it. In the meantime, you can try changing everything to the right of the `|` to read `sudo -u absonegative dd of=temp-backup.tar.gz`